# workbook_open not working when starting excel 2010 workbook from vbs

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am using Excel 2010. I am opening test.xls file from VBS (VB script) using the below code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("E:\test\test.xls")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
```

the workbook test.xls opens fine, but the workbook_open macro that I put inside Thisworkbook Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

doesn't run.

It works when I open test.xls directly, but not through VB Script.

I have set Developer > Macro Security > Macro Settings to Enable all Macros, 
but this still doesn't help.

Comment: Works for me. You may want to try disabling Protected View, if it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same issue. Here is what I did.

1. Save your file as .xlsm(marco-enabled excel).
2. Instead of writing your code in worksheet, create new module and copy your VBA code in a function or sub with name like 'Excel_Macro'.
3. Include the following two line in your VBS code (from where you are opening excel).

objExcel.Run("Excel_Macro")

This worked for me.

Comment: Reason for your issuee: You are attempting to work with the Workbook events, which are local to the object to which they belong (in this case, the add-in). What you need is an Application event.